# "?" character in hex string conversion

Tags: python

Why does a "?" character appear in the following hex value? (I am using Python 3.5.1)

My aim is to convert `string` into hex value pairs.

```
string = b'3f8ccccd'
hexpairs = binascii.unhexlify(string)
```

The value for `hexpairs` I get is this:

```
b'?\x8c\xcc\xcd'
```

What is the significance of the `?` character? I would have expected the output to have been:

```
b'\x3f\x8c\xcc\xcd'
```

Comment: The bytes whose values correspond to characters in ASCII are displayed as these characters. And 0x3F is the ASCII code for "?"

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: @Hefaestion if you want the output as written as your expected string: `"".join("\\x{}".format(char.decode()) for char in (string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2))).encode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ? occurs due to the fact that unhexlify has used 3F as a byte code, which is the ASCII code for '?'. Thus, Python has displayed these bytes as an ASCII code.

Answer (score 2):

@Benedict answer's is correct, Here is some sources to help you understand:

- [binascii.unhexlify()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) official python documentation.
- [wikipedia -- ascii table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

> Originally based on the English alphabet, ASCII encodes 128 specified
>   characters into seven-bit integers as shown by the ASCII chart
>   above.[8] The characters encoded are numbers 0 to 9, lowercase letters
>   a to z, uppercase letters A to Z, basic punctuation symbols, control
>   codes that originated with Teletype machines, and a space. For
>   example, lowercase j would become binary 1101010 and decimal 106.
>   ASCII includes definitions for 128 characters: 33 are non-printing
>   control characters (many now obsolete)[9] that affect how text and
>   space are processed[10] and 95 printable characters, including the
>   space

- [The ascii table values](http://ascii.cl/)
- [Convertor to hexa, decimal, octal, ascii](http://calc.50x.eu/)

For `?` character:

- *binary*: 00111111. in python, `chr(0b00111111)` will output `?`
- *octal*: 77.        in python `chr(0o77)`        will output `?`
- *decimal*: 63.      in python `chr(63)`          will output `?`
- *hexadecimal*: 3F.    in python `chr(0x3f)`        will output `?`

As you can see, you can use prefixes like `0b`, `0o`, or `0x` before `int` to make python understand you are not working with decimal numbers.

However `0x8C` is out of the ascii table (because it goes from 0 to 127). `0x8C` being 140 in decimal it cannot display the equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

This problem can be solved by the below given way.

```
hexastring = r'\xc3\xb9asdfsadf\xc3\xa9 asdfsdfsdf \xc3\x80 sdfsdfsdfdsf \xc3\xba'

hexaValueList = re.findall(r'((?:\\x[a-f\d]{2})+)',hexastring)
for hexaValue in hexaValueList:
    beforeReplace = hexaValue
    xReplace = re.sub(r'\\x','',hexaValue)
    hex2String = bytearray.fromhex(xReplace).decode()
    hexastring = re.sub(re.escape(beforeReplace),hex2String,hexastring)

print (hexastring)
```

Answer

ùasdfsadfé asdfsdfsdf À sdfsdfsdfdsf ú